# How to use query parameters in GCP BigQuery federated queries

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a gcp based environment. I use standard SQL scripting in gcp BigQuery and federated query to cloudsql MySql.  Federated query selects data from cloudsql mysql database. I need to select data from cloudsql mysql database based on condition that depends on data in BigQuery. I use variables in standard sql scriping in gcp bigquery to store the value that I select from bigquery. I want to value of this variable in the where clause of mysql query. See following example where I select a date from BigQuery and store it in a variable "BQ_LAST_DATETIME".

```sql
    DECLARE BQ_LAST_DATETIME DATETIME
    SET BQ_LAST_DATETIME = (select max(date_created) from bq_my_dataset.bq_my_table);
```

Since I am using bigquery federated query to read data out of cloudsql database (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries) as shown below and I want to use value that I stored in the variable "BQ_LAST_DATETIME" in the mysql query where clause

```sql
   SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("my-gcp-project.my-region.my-connection2-cloudsql", "select * from mysqlschema.mysql_table where where date_created = @BQ_LAST_DATETIME;" );
```

Please note that in above query I have used "@BQ_LAST_DATETIME" as a placeholder to show what I want to achieve. I am not sure if I can directly use bigquery scripting variable as query parameter in the "external" query part of federated query.
Any suggestions on how to achieve parametrization of external queries in  federated query, or if you know  how I could achieve effect similar to what my intent is?

I actually tried following  as depicted .  I  used bigquery scripting variable as query parameter in the "external" query part of federated query. only nuance here is that since the I was dealing with dates I performed a cast and also since the date variable actually is treated as a string I  formatted it back to date using mysql STR_TO_DATE as follows

```sql
    DECLARE BQ_LAST_DATETIME DATETIME
    SET BQ_LAST_DATETIME = (select max(date_created) from bq_my_dataset.bq_my_table);
    SET BQ_LAST_DATE= CAST(BQ_LAST_DATETIME  AS DATE);
    SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("my-gcp-project.my-region.my-connection2-cloudsql", "select * from mysqlschema.mysql_table where where date_created =  STR_TO_DATE(@BQ_LAST_DATE,'%Y-%m-%d') ;" );
```

While this query is accepted by parser it is NOT giving expected result.
Basically the value of the variable @BQ_LAST_DATE does not seem to get to MySQL query as expected.

Does anyone know what am I missing ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: What is this scripting language called? Is it unique to bigquery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`:

```
DECLARE BQ_LAST_DATETIME STRING;
DECLARE DSQL STRING;
SET BQ_LAST_DATETIME = 'SELECT max(date_created) from bq_my_dataset.bq_my_table';
SET DSQL = '"select * from mysqlschema.mysql_table where date_created = (' || BQ_LAST_DATETIME || ')"';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("my-gcp-project.my-region.my-connection2-cloudsql",' || DSQL || ');'
```

Comment: thanks a lot Soumendra Mishra This sure gets me moving

Comment: This solution is perfect. Basically the DSQL string is a dynamically created string that I built using SET keyword that parses and substitutes variable values using the  construct  ' || BQ_LAST_DATETIME || ' . and execute immediate then executes this dynamically constructed string that has my variable values . Awesome !!!

Comment: Glad that you liked the solution. Please consider accepting this answer !

Comment: Thanks Soumendra Mishra!  This enables sync via scheduled queries — invaluable.

Comment: I get the following error that I am unable to make sense of. `invalid table-valued function external_query Failed to get query schema from MySQL server. Error: MysqlErrorCode(1142): SELECT command denied to user 'XXX@'cloudsqlproxy~' for table 'XXX' at [1:22] at [1:1]`.

Comment: I just posted it as a separate question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70680576/gcp-bigquery-query-parameters-in-federated-queries

Comment: it looks like to me, the `BQ_LAST_DATETIME` is also executed against external connection and NOT against bq dataset, which causes the error. Does anyone know if something has changed by now and causing this error.

Comment: Some related info: 1. thanks very much Soumendra Mishra! This was a really helpful workaround. 2. Note there is an open ticket to add param passing to EXTERNAL_QUERY - please upvote if this affects you, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154388185. 3. Unfortunately, if you're trying to use this solution to pass parameters from a Looker/Google Data Studio report it won't work, as custom queries in Looker only allow for a single statement: https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/6370296#custom-query .

Answer (score -1):

So I figured - it works almost as depicted .. that means you can directly use bigquery scripting variable as query parameter in the "external" query part of federated query. only nuance here is that since the I was dealing with dates I performed a cast and also since the date variable actually is treated as a string I had to format it back to date using mysql STR_TO_DATE as follows

```
enter code here
 DECLARE DATE_FROM_BIGQUERY_DATA DATETIME
 SET BQ_LAST_DATETIME = (select max(date_created) from bq_my_dataset.bq_my_table);
 SET LAST_DATE= CAST(LAST_DATETIME  AS DATE);
SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("my-gcp-project.my-region.my-connection2-cloudsql", "select * from mysqlschema.mysql_table where where date_created =  STR_TO_DATE(@BQ_LAST_DATE,'%Y-%m-%d') ;" );
```