# GCP Bigquery - query parameters in federated queries

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I am failing to implement the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66011037/2296728) proposed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65995449/how-to-use-query-parameters-in-gcp-bigquery-federated-queries).

My sql code:

```
declare bq_last_id string;
declare external_sql string;
set bq_last_id = 'select max(id) from bq_dataset.bq_table';
set external_sql = '"select * from mysql_table where id > ('|| bq_last_id ||')"';
execute immediate 'select * from external_query("my-gcp-project.my-region.my-connection-name",'|| external_sql || ');'
```

I get the following error

> invalid table-valued function external_query Failed to get query
> schema from MySQL server. Error: MysqlErrorCode(1142): SELECT command
> denied to user 'XXX@'cloudsqlproxy~' for table 'XXX' at [1:22] at
> [1:1]

If I hard code the value of bq_last_id like this, it works fine.

```
set external_sql = '"select * from mysql_table where id > 123456"';
```

EDIT 1:
I printed the statement before execute statement and it looks like this, and that looks fine to me I guess.

```
select * from external_query("my-gcp-project.my-region.my-connection-name", "select * from mysql_table where id > (select max(id) from bq_dataset.bq_table)");
```

EDIT 2:
Finally I had to insert data back so using the answer below and a one more bracket I was able to do it this way.

```
declare bq_last_id int64; # Change the type here
declare external_sql string;
set bq_last_id = (select max(id) from bq_dataset.bq_table); # put the query in parenthesis to force BQ to evaluate it
set external_sql = '"select * from mysql_table where id > ('|| bq_last_id ||')"';
execute immediate 'insert into bq_dataset.bq_table (select * from external_query("my-gcp-project.my-region.my-connection-name",'|| external_sql || '))'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure of the query generated? Did you try to print it before your execute immediate?

Comment: I added an edit to show what it looks like before execute immediate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to your update, here the issue: You query your Cloud SQL instance with a BQ table in reference. That can't work. You must evaluate the max(id) before adding it to your query, like that

```
declare bq_last_id int64; # Change the type here
declare external_sql string;
set bq_last_id = (select max(id) from bq_dataset.bq_table); # put the query in parenthesis to force BQ to evaluate it
set external_sql = '"select * from mysql_table where id > ('|| bq_last_id ||')"';
execute immediate 'select * from external_query("my-gcp-project.my-region.my-connection-name",'|| external_sql || ');'
```