# Debugging a bigquery federated query with variables

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

so i'm trying to build an incremental update system for my tables in bigquery with source as Cloud SQL MySQL database. For that I am using federated queries and I'd like to query data that has been updated after a certain timestamp.

I have based my query on this question's answer: [How to use query parameters in GCP BigQuery federated queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65995449/how-to-use-query-parameters-in-gcp-bigquery-federated-queries/66011037#66011037)

To obtain:

```
DECLARE BQ_LAST_DATETIME STRING;
DECLARE DSQL STRING;
SET BQ_LAST_DATETIME = "SELECT MAX(updated_at) FROM `dataset.table`";
SET DSQL = '"SELECT * FROM mysql_table WHERE updated_at > ('|| BQ_LAST_DATETIME ||')"';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("mygcpproject.region.database",'|| DSQL||');'
```

THIS did not work because the bigquery query to set BQ_LAST_DATETIME was being run in mysql hence not finding the table.

so I found out that you have to evaluate the first SELECT, which led to this:

```
DECLARE BQ_LAST_DATETIME TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE DSQL STRING;
SET BQ_LAST_DATETIME = (SELECT MAX(updated_at) FROM `dataset.table`);
SET DSQL = '"SELECT * FROM mysql_table WHERE updated_at > ('|| BQ_LAST_DATETIME ||')"';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("mygcpproject.region.database",'|| DSQL||');'
```

This did not work either because the query will have something like:

```
SELECT * FROM mysql_table WHERE updated_at > 16-09-2022 15:25:00
```

where it should be:

```
SELECT * FROM mysql_table WHERE updated_at > '16-09-2022 15:25:00'
```

Does anybody know how to do that ?
Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try one of followings:

1. use an escaped quote(`\'`) instead of `(` and `)`.

```sql
SET DSQL = '"SELECT * FROM mysql_table WHERE updated_at > \''|| BQ_LAST_DATETIME ||'\'"';
```

2. use a formatted string with triple quotes `"""` in **[FORMAT()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#format_string)** function.

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY(
    "mygcpproject.region.database",
    "SELECT * FROM mysql_table WHERE updated_at > '%s'"
  );
""", STRING(BQ_LAST_DATETIME));
```